# How to fill a Google chart with PHP from a TXT data file?

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have a `DATAS.TXT` file automatically filled-in with TIME and TEMPERATURE datas.

TIME is already formatted as per Google Charts requirements:
`new Date(Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes)`

TIME datas and TEMPERATURES datas are separated by a **SPACE character** and each line terminates with **`\r`**.

The `DATAS.TXT` file shows something like this:

```
new Date(2017, 01, 01, 05, 15) 20.5
new Date(2017, 01, 01, 18, 50) 21.7
new Date(2017, 01, 19, 12, 35) 22.4
```

etc ...

From this DATA file I would like to generate a Google Chart like this example:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['annotatedtimeline']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Temperatures');
    data.addRows([
        [new Date(2001,  0,  1,  0), 0.0],
        [new Date(2001,  0,  1,  1), 4.8],
        [new Date(2001,  0,  1,  2), 4.6],
        [new Date(2001,  0,  1,  3), 2.6],
        [new Date(2001,  0,  1,  4), 3.6],
        // ...
        // Rest of year data here...
        // ...
        [new Date(2001, 11, 31, 20), 9.4],
        [new Date(2001, 11, 31, 21), 7.0],
        [new Date(2001, 11, 31, 22), 8.5],
        [new Date(2001, 11, 31, 23), 2.2]
        ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {displayAnnotations: true});

}

</script>
```

My question is, how can I fill-in `data.addRows([ ... ]` contents with the datas issued from my `DATAS.TXT` file?

I need a function that could pick-up TIMES, detect the space character insertion, pick-up the associated TEMPERATURE data and detect the `\r` character.

I'm not confortable with PHP, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: When you write “/r", do you mean carriage return, eg. `\r`?

Comment: Yes, you are right it is carriage return \r